# Why does gulp watch continuously output starting\finished to terminal

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

After migrating gulp to gulp 4, terminal continuously outputs "Starting" and "Finished" after a single change\save to a scss file. **Is this normal?** The script is doing it's job, but the infinite output does not seem right. My script is small, so maybe someone sees something that I do not. My site is running on localhost IIS 7.5 website with bindings set to IP address. 
Help is much appreciated. Thanks!

The only gulp migration added is **gulp.series('css')**

```
var sitename = 'mysitename';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
postcss = require('gulp-postcss'),
sass = require('gulp-sass'),
sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
newer = require('gulp-newer'),

// Name of working theme folder
root = '../' + sitename + '/',
scss = root + 'sass/';

// CSS via Sass and Autoprefixer
gulp.task('css', function() {
    return gulp.src(scss + '{style.scss,rtl.scss}')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass({
        outputStyle: 'compressed', 
        indentType: 'tab',
        indentWidth: '1'
    }).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(postcss([
        autoprefixer('last 2 versions', '> 1%')
    ]))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write(scss + 'maps'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(root + '/dist/css/'))
    //.pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

// Watch everything
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    browserSync.init({ 
        open: 'external',
        host: 'example.com',
        proxy: 'example.com',
        port: 80
    });
    gulp.watch([root + '**/*.css', root + '**/*.scss' ], gulp.series('css') );
    gulp.watch(root + '**/*').on('change', browserSync.reload);
});
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('watch') );
```

### If my style.scss file is saved, terminal output continues infinitely...

```
C:\Workspace\mysite\gulp-dev>gulp  
[12:00:37] Using gulpfile  
C:\Workspace\mysite\gulp-dev\gulpfile.js   
[12:00:37] Starting 'default'...   
[12:00:37] Starting 'watch'...   
[Browsersync] Proxying: http://example.com   
[Browsersync] Access URLs:   
-----------------------------------  
       Local: http://localhost:81  
    External: http://example.com:81    
-----------------------------------  
          UI: http://localhost:3001    
UI External: http://example.com:3001    
-----------------------------------   
[12:00:48] Starting 'css'...   
[12:00:48] Finished 'css' after 117 ms   
[12:00:48] Starting 'css'...   
[12:00:48] Finished 'css' after 32 ms   
[12:00:48] Starting 'css'...   
[12:00:48] Finished 'css' after 55 ms   
[12:00:48] Starting 'css'...   
[12:00:48] Finished 'css' after 63 ms   
[12:00:49] Starting 'css'...   
[12:00:49] Finished 'css' after 26 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

It is occurring because you are watching the folder you are outputting the css to:

```
gulp.watch([root + '**/*.css'

.pipe(gulp.dest(root + '/dist/css/')
```

> If a "globstar" [the **] is alone in a path portion, then it matches zero or
>   more directories and subdirectories searching for matches.

"**And subdirectories**" is the part that is catching you.  So your "`root/**/.css`" includes "`root/dist/css`".  Everytime the 'css' task is riggered it writes to the folder you are watching again, so the task gets retriggered...etc.  This is why you don't usually watch your entire root, just wherever the src is located and then write out to a different place.

[glob primer](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#glob-primer)